# Can any function be rewritten as a composition of functions on $x$?

Tags: analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Many functions use forms that have multiple instances of $x$, including polynomials and rational functions. However, finding the domain and range can be simpler when they are written with only one use of $x$. It can also make transformations more clear.

For example, the polynomial function $f(x) = x^2-10x+35$ can be rewritten as $f(x) = \left(x-5\right)^2+10$.

By composition of functions, I mean that:

$$f(x) = x^2-10x+35$$

But it can be rewritten as a composition of functions on $x$, with each composed function *only using $x$ once*:

$$f(x)=g(h(i(x)))$$
$$g(x)=x+10$$
$$h(x)=x^2$$
$$i(x)=x-5$$

However, I cannot figure out how some rational functions can be rewritten in this form, such as:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

Can any function be written with only one use of $x$?

Comment: Consider the Kolmogorov result that any real-valued continuous function on the unit interval can be represented by a Kolmogorov network.

Comment: So what you call a "function on $x$" is a function "with only one use of $x$"? Then what if we write $h(x)=x\cdot x$ instead of $h(x)=x^2$? Before sensible things can be said first the vague concepts around must be defined rigorously.

Comment: I think not, and is related to if a number is algebraic, transcendental, and fundamental to notion of field extensions. See field extension.you seem to ask about field of integers, and it rational extension?

Comment: @drhab Sorry, I'll make it more clear that each composed function must have one use of $x$, I'm not sure if there is a more formal term for it.

Comment: @KabirShah Will you allow $g(x)=x$, $h(x)=x^2+1$, $k(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$, so $k(g(x), h(x)) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$ ?

Comment: @gandalf61 No, because this case is restricted to single variable functions. I'm essentially looking for a function that uses one instance of $x$ and the rest being constants.

Comment: can $x^4-1$ and $x^3-x$ be done then the example unknown is related to those via the reciprocal function.